# HQL Select new as column

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is it possible in HQL to get a column as an object? I mean something like this:

```
select p.name as name, new Property(p.color, p.brand) as properties from Product p
```

Transforming the result into:

```
public class ProductInfo {
    private String name;
    private Property properties;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

The previous query doesn't work:

```
line 1:5731: unexpected token: new
```

So I want to know if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: The answer is in the question, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question several times. Do you mean it's impossible? And there is any way to retrieve a column as an object?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a quick solution would be to get Product then proceed to the creation of ProductInfo.

Note that it only suits for one result, if you have to process many others this solution might not be the best option.